# Using Postman with gRPCS

Tags: postman, grpc

I have a grpc endpoint hello.mydomain.io, exposed on port 80 (unencrypted) and port 443 (tls with a public trusted certificate)

Both of these are are reachable with grpcurl without difficulty:

```
me:~$ ./grpcurl -v  hello.mydomain.io:443 list
addsvc.Add
grpc.gateway.examples.examplepb.ABitOfEverythingService
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
grpcbin.GRPCBin
hello.HelloService

me:~$ ./grpcurl -v --plaintext  hello.mydomain.io:80 list
addsvc.Add
grpc.gateway.examples.examplepb.ABitOfEverythingService
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
grpcbin.GRPCBin
hello.HelloService
```

However when I try from Postman (latest v9.21.2), only port 80 works, while the secure endpoint is stuck "Invoking method..." forever. Hoping there's some easy configuration that fixes this!

Comment: Is there anything in the [Postman's Console](https://blog.postman.com/the-postman-console/)?

Comment: @phuzi Nope, it's just blank with both requests- guessing it's not implemented yet with grpc?

Comment: Postman [should support GRPC](https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-grpc/) (but only v9.7.1 and later).

Comment: It might just be a bug (https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10902#issuecomment-1153816945), will see once that's resolved.